# Programmatically register/deregister intent-filter for an activity

Tags: android, intentfilter

Assume that I have app X, with Activity A which is launched by some intent filer F defined in X's manifest file.

Is it possible for X to programmatically deregister/register intent filter F for A?

Is is possible for another app Y to programmatically deregister/register intent filter F for A, given that I have access to both app X and Y and can set any required permissions?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I need to programmatically register intent inside my activity and then deregister it...

Answer (score 0):

For example, 
if two applications need to communicate with one another, they can do so by using the object type Binder instead of using complex protocols ICP.

1. Each application for security reasons should be signed with the same key,
2. Each application should be run always with the same user identifier.
3. Declare all the relevant activities or components

Answer (score 0):

You can not register / Deregister `intent-filter` programatically. But what you can use `Broadcast Receiver` for the same purpose. Something like :

```
registerReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
```

and Unregister it like :

```
if (this.broadcastReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver);
    }
```